# Confusing property of definite integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Consider the proof of the property

> $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)dx$$

Solution :-

Let $t = a + b - x$  then,

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-t) dt$$

The next step is confusing.

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)dx \tag{Taking t=x}$$

How can we take such a substitution since $t$ is given as $a+b-x$

Comment: The letter inside the integral does not matter. Then it is no important if the variable is $t$ or $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable name inside an integral is a *dummy variable*; its name is irrelevant. You can use any name you want:
$$
\int_a^b f(x) \; dx = \int_a^b f(z) \; dz = \int_a^b f(\tau) \; d\tau = \int_a^b f(\zeta) \; d\zeta = \int_a^b f(t) \; dt.
$$
The name following the $d$ at the end tells you what is to be varied between $a$ and $b$.

So,
$$
\int_a^b f(a + b - t) \; dt = \int_a^b f(a+b-x) \; dx.
$$

Comment: how can we equate t = x since t is equal to a+b-x

Comment: @Vinayak: we're not, really. The name is irrelevant. Maybe it'll help you to write $\int_a^b f(a+b-t)\,dt = \int_a^b f(a+b-z)\,dz$  (because you can use any letter you want...) and then find that equals $ \int_a^b f(a+b-x)\,dx$.

Answer (score 0):

If $F(x)$ is a primitive of $f(x)$, then $-F(a+b-x)$ is a primitive of $f(a+b-x)$.